# run x64 executable in emulated arm docker

Tags: docker, cross-compiling

Is it possible to run a x64 executable in a linux arm docker that is emulated on a x64 machine?

I would like to use this to achieve fast cross compilations without changing the architecture of the build system or docker image. I currently compile C++ and C source code in the arm docker but all executables are emulated via QEMU which results in very slow compile times. If the compiler and linker executable were instead x64 executables the whole process would be accelerated.

I know that there is a working alternative for this approach which id like to avoid:

- Extract the whole docker filesystem on the host system
- Use clang or gcc with the `--sysroot` argument to cross compile using this extracted filesystem

Comment: If we skip the docker-stage, would you expect to be able to run an x86-64 program in an ARM system? If not, then why do you think you would be able to do it in an ARM system emulator?

Comment: Trying to understand the question, are looking for a C/C++ cross compiler?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude maybe the kernel could somehow recognize that the system can actually start x64 executables and not only arm executables.

Comment: @BMitch im interested in running the cross compiler inside the arm docker because this way a docker image could be built that contains everything that is needed for fast compilation on x64, testing the programs with emulation and running the programs on actual arm devices.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've experienced a qemu-system-aarch64 VM on x86_64 host executing x86_64 executables inside docker containers in the aarch64 emulator.  Running the same environment in an Apple M1 MacOS multipass VM results in unloadable/non-executable libraries/binaries when the environment is not completely ported to aarch64 (ultimately much different behavior on an M1 versus an emulated aarch64 environment).

Answer (score 0):

From the docker side, this is fairly straightforward using buildkit. You would create a Dockerfile that contains something like:

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM your_build_image as build
WORKDIR /src/
COPY . /src/
ARG TARGETOS
ARG TARGETARCH
RUN make cross-compile-${TARGETOS}-${TARGETARCH}

FROM your_target_image
COPY --from=build /src/app /usr/local/bin/app
```

The key parts in there:

- `--platform=$BUILDPLATFORM`: this uses an image that matches your builder OS/architecture, rather than the target you are building
- `${TARGETOS}` and `${TARGETARCH}` these are injected automatically by buildx and refer to the Go GOOS and GOARCH values (since Docker is written in Go).

The `RUN make ...` depends on how you build your app for different platforms, change that as appropriate along with adjusting the paths in the `COPY`.

With that, you can run:

```sh
# if you have buildkit enabled and want a single platform image
docker build --platform=linux/amd64 .
# or use buildx for creating multiplatform images, this requires pushing to a registry
docker buildx build --platform=linux/amd64,linux/arm64 --push -t $REGISTRY/$IMAGE:$TAG .
```

from a `linux/arm64` system and BUILDPLATFORM will be set to `linux/arm64`, `TARGETOS=linux`, and `TARGETARCH=amd64`.

You can see more about the automatic build args in the [Dockerfile docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#automatic-platform-args-in-the-global-scope).

Beyond that, if you need help doing the actual C/C++ cross compile, that will likely need someone else to help, maybe a separate question including an example of errors you're encountering.